# Django Autocomplete light & taggit - custom styling of results

Tags: django-taggit, django-autocomplete-light

I am using django-autocomplete-light with django-taggit. The integration is very easy if you follow the documentation:

```
import autocomplete_light
from taggit.models import Tag
autocomplete_light.register(Tag)
```

and

```
class NewActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tags = TagField(widget=TagWidget('TagAutocomplete'))
    [...]
```

This renders a nice inline-style widget where you type and you see the autocomplete list below - everything is fine.

However, my tags are color-coded, so I need to customize two things:

a) First, in the autocomplete list, I need to customize the css class of each tag. I get some control over the template, but it seems there are css selectors looking for [data-value] that override my classes. The code for autocomplete_template_html is:

```
<div>
    {% for choice in choices %}
        <span class="tag tag--{{choice.pk}}" data-value="{{choice.pk}}" >{{choice}}</span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

b) Second, once a tag is selected and added to my input, I need to maintain that css class there so I get a custom look. When I see the generated DOM elements, I see that there are some hidden spans in there that I could perhaps use, but it's not clear how to do.

How can I do this? Should I write my own widget or is there something I can subclass?

Answer (score 1):

### A) Can't override CSS class

It looks like a [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) problem.

I just tried this and it works if it is set **after** loading `autocomplete_light/style.css` (or `autocomplete_light/static.html' template):

```
    .yourlabs-autocomplete .choice, .yourlabs-autocomplete [data-value], .yourlabs-autocomplete em
    {   
        color: red;
    }
```

Else, you could just [override `autocomplete_light/static/autocomplete_light/style.css`](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/30382323418/surviving-django-contrib-staticfiles-or-how-to-manage).

### B) Style must be the same when a choice is selected

When a choice is selected, it's HTML is copied to the deck, only `span.remove` is added. The style should remain.

It would help a lot if posted your CSS though !

Comment: So - I would like to add some extra HTML to my selected element in the deck in part B.  A select box for example, associated with the autocomplete selection.  I want the value of this select box to be posted when I submit the form.  How best to accomplish that?